# Fats' words were fairly persuasive

Tags: vocabulary, modal-verbs

> (1) Andrew's words were persuasive. 
>   (2) Fats' words were fairly persuasive.

Sentence (1) is a preposition; in (2) adverb, fairly, is added. Whose words were more persuasive to the speaker, if the speaker the same one?
In this contrast, '(3) *he is a liar*,' and '(4) *he must be a liar*,' the former must be stronger, Applied to this, (1) could be more persuasive. But is that really so?

Comment: @Araucaria That was a typo. He meant to say "proposition."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How persuasive would depend on the context. There's no absolute answer, unless the two forms were used side-by-side.

**Fats must be fairly persuasive to convince you that he runs marathons on weekends.**

There, "fairly" is an intensifier, like "quite" or "rather".

```
 Did you do well on the test?
 -- I did fairly well.
```

There, "fairly"  might mean a good performance, but not as good a performance as hoped. It isn't a foregone conclusion that one could substitute "quite" or "rather" for "fairly" there.

It would depend on the intonation pattern.

```
I did fáirly well.   (I could have done better. I'm disappointed.)

I did fairly wéll.   (I did quite well. I'm pleased.)
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about it until this question, but yes, it is quite confusing how "fairly" can provide opposite meanings...